# Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly error message

Tags: php, apache, xampp, php-7.1, php-7.2

I just upgraded the PHP version of XAMPP from PHP 7.1.7 to PHP 7.2.0 using the guidelines from this [article](https://www.techflirt.com/how-to-upgrade-php-in-xampp/).

Then I tried restarting the XAMPP but I got this error:

```
10:54:47 AM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
10:54:47 AM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:54:47 AM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:54:47 AM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:54:47 AM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:54:47 AM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:54:47 AM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

After that I opened up my Skype and in the Connection tab, I disabled the checkobox "**Use port 80 and 443 for alternatives for incoming connections**". Then I tried restarting the Apache but again I got the error message.

Next thing that I did was changing the `Listen 80` to `Listen 1372` in  **httpd.conf** and also the `ServerName localhost:80` to `ServerName localhost:1372` in the same file. And then tried to start the Apache but one more time I got the same error.

I also changed this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

ServerName www.example.com:443
```

to this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:4433>

ServerName localhost:4433
```

in the **httpd-ssl.conf** file. But until now the Apache can not start and returns the same error message.

So what should I do now?

Comment: What does the Windows Event Log say?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil What is windows event log ?

Comment: [https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749408(v=ws.11).aspx](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749408(v=ws.11).aspx)

Comment: Try starting it from you CMD: C:/path/to/xampp/apache_start.bat
This will give you more info on your problem some times and you can also try to to look up witch applications uses port 80 and 443 the main port apache and httpd uses `netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:443`

Comment: Then it says can not start :(

Comment: and if you run `netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:443` what is it the output?

Comment: Gave Andrew Osenga an up vote for C:/path/to/xampp/apache_start.bat suggestion. In my case it was a syntax error which I found straight away. Doh!!

Answer (score 4):

Goto Apache config -> Apache (httpd.config) -> change "Listen 80 to 81"

on broswer-> http://localhost:81/phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 1):

Go to C:\xampp\mysql\backup.

Copy all files.

Paste them into C:\xampp\mysql\data.

If Windows asks you to replace some files, replace them.

If your XAMPP Control Panes is active close it.

Go to C:\xampp and find xampp-control, run it.

Start Apache, start MySQL.

---

That's it.

Enjoy!

Comment: There is file called setup xampp, run it and open xampp control then start Apache and MySql .

Its worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

just change this

ServerName [www.example.com:443](http://www.example.com:443)

to this

ServerName [www.example.com:4433](http://www.example.com:4433)

and
change this
ServerName localhost:80
Listen 80
to this

ServerName localhost:8080
Listen 8080

Answer (score -2):

please do these steps as well

In the Control Panel, click on the main Config button again.
Click on Service and Port Settings.
Change the Main Port to 8080 and the SSL Port 4433.
Close out of Configuration.
Stop and Start Apache.
Click the Admin button by Apache and it should open up the XAMPP home page in your browser.

I hope this will work!

Answer (score -3):

If you have installed Skype Software .

Then Open Skype:

Go to Menu:

Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection.

Uncheck the "Use port 80 and 443 for additional for incoming connections"

Sign Out and Close the Skype software. Then restart your Apache.